# Default weird CSS property in NextJS setup - zoom: 1.1

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Although I have already solved the problem, I still wonder what the author of this solution could mean + I hope it helps others who can potentially face this issue.

I installed the newest NextJS 13.2.4 on my machine. I ran into a problem while styling something super simple - *setting 100vh on parent container that is wrapping sign-in form and some image*.

**JSX**

```
<section className={classes.section}> //here setting height: 100vh;
        <div className={classes['section__form']}>
          <SignInForm />
        </div>
        <div className={classes['section__img']}>
          <img src="/images/sign-in.jpg"></img>
        </div>
      </section>
```

**What problem I faced?**

- The actual page wasn't `100vh` but went way above that.
- Due to visual aspects I couldn't agree with having an unnecessary scroll bar.

In my `globals.scss` I always set.

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Despite my global settings, the page had a scrollbar and went beyond `100vh`.

After hours of being confused ... I figured out in Chrome dev tools that on `body` by default there's such a `zoom` property set.

```
 body {
 zoom: 1.1;
}
```

I don't know where this property exists in my project files but based on dev tools, this tag automatically gets added to the html document.

```
<style id="zoompage-zoomlevel-style" type="text/css">body { zoom: 1.1; }</style>
```

I think it's somewhere deep in the NextJS setup files.

**SOLUTION**

In `globals.scss` I added

```
body {
  zoom: 1 !important;
}
```

while without `!important`  rule it wouldn't override the existing property `zoom: 1.1`.

[image]

I wonder if that's some sort of a bug or there's something interesting/beneficial that stands behind it?

Maciej

---

**PERMANENT FIX**

**Zoom Page WE Chrome plugin** causes this issue (adds this extra line to the html document). If you face any similar problems, make sure you have this plugin uninstalled and the problem will disappear.

Comment: I'm running 13.2.4 in my current project and I don't have this zoom value in my app. Honestly this looks like a browser plugin that's setting the css. Have you tested it in a private window without plugins?

Comment: Looks like it's this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-page-we/bcdjhkphgmiapajkphennjfgoehpodpk

I found this after a google of `zoompage-zoomlevel-style` and reading this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1449875

Comment: Hi Sebi, thank you for your response. I have no idea why I had this plugin installed but it caused that weird unexpected behavior. It's interesting because this plugin did not clash with any of my previous projects, till now. It's all clear now. I uninstalled it and no more extra `zoom` property is added to `body`. All works as expected. Massive thanks Sebi! :)